# How to change the background color of toolkit:PickerBox when opened in fullmode?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am using

```
    <toolkit:PickerBox/>
```

How to change the background of it to a different color when opened in FullMode?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the PickerBoxPage.xaml from the location /Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/PickerBox/PickerBoxPage.xaml to your local project folder.

Edit the background of the page to your desired background color.

Set the PickerPageUri of the toolkit:PickerBox to : your_localfolder_name/PickerBoxPage.xaml

For example:

```
    <toolkit:PickerBox PickerPageUri="/View/PickerBoxPage.xaml" />
```

Its all done.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Previously in `xaml` we were using DataTriggers for such purposes. In WinRT as well as WP8 apps this concept was eliminated. You can use Visual States instead:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Maximized">
  <Storyboard>
     <ColorAnimation To="Green" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContentContainer.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Duration="0"/>
  </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

To change `VisualState` depending on the size of `PickerBox` you'll have to use behavior which will change states depending on pickers size (subscribe to the `SizeChanged` event):

```
private void SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
     UpdateVisualState();
}

private void UpdateVisualState()
{
    var state = string.Empty;

    // calculate state here (Normal vs Maximized)

    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, state, true);
}
```

Comment: I didnt try your method since I got it working another way. Thanks for your reply.